Making linear extrapolation only start at a specific frame
I've created a walk cycle that uses linear extrapolation to continue. I want to make the walk cycle start and repeat after a specific keyframe, is this possible?

normally you have to just use the cycle modifier for all keyframes except the "root" bone (which is in mixamo the spine bone) which you have to move just linear extrapolate. did u try that? if yes, and it didn't work, pls provide blend file

Thank you, this works. Had no idea that was a thing.
